# How to set app_id and app_secret properties in Jmeter before running some tests on a application?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I'm using J-meter to load test an application.

How to actually set **app_id** and **app_secret** in J-Meter for running tests?, and where can i find them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are testing an application which is using [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) and most probably it is [Facebook-based](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).

If my assumption is correct, then you can get the `app_id` and `app_secret` from your application dashboard

[image: FaceBook Appid Appsecret JMeter]

More information:

- [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)
- [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)